# How to concatenate multiple data frames with long index without error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, valueerror

I have a directory ".../dados" in which have multiple subdirectories whose names are a serial number plus some useless information - e.g. "17448_2017_Jul_2017_Oct", where the first number on it is the serial number. Inside each subdirectory, I have four ".txt" files whose lines/rows have the information of date and time, and an attribute of a certain type, say humidity, all named the same way in each subdirectory - e.g. "2019-01-29 03:11:26 54.7".

I want to concatenate all of them in order to generate a dataset with date index.

```
path = "/.../dados/"

df = pd.DataFrame()

for fld in os.listdir(path):
    subfld = path + fld
    if os.path.isdir(subfld):
        aux = pd.DataFrame()
        sn = fld.split('_')[0]
        for file in os.listdir(subfld):
            filepath = os.path.join(subfld, file)
            if os.path.isfile(filepath):
                new_col = pd.read_fwf(filepath, colspecs=[(0, 19), (20, -1)], skiprows=8, names=[file.split('_')[2][:-4]], parse_dates=[0], nrows=9999999)
                aux = pd.concat([aux, new_col], axis=1,  sort=False)
        aux['Machine'] = sn
        df = df.append(aux)
```

This is a print of df.head(10):

```
HumTechRoom  TempTechRoom  TempExamRoom  HumExamRoom Machine
2018-03-04 00:45:11         82.6           NaN           NaN          NaN   22162
2018-03-04 00:45:47         80.0           NaN           NaN          NaN   22162
2018-03-04 00:45:53         78.0           NaN           NaN          NaN   22162
2018-03-04 00:46:04         75.9           NaN           NaN          NaN   22162
2018-03-04 00:46:20         73.7           NaN           NaN         51.3   22162
2018-03-04 00:46:58         71.7           NaN           NaN          NaN   22162
2018-03-04 00:47:40          NaN           NaN           NaN         53.4   22162
2018-03-04 00:47:41          NaN          14.5           NaN          NaN   22162
2018-03-04 00:47:54         74.3           NaN           NaN          NaN   22162
2018-03-04 00:47:59         76.6           NaN           NaN          NaN   22162
```

THis is the error message that I get:

```
...
line 31, in <module>
    aux = pd.concat([aux, new_col], axis=1,  sort=False)

  File ".../concat.py", line 226, in concat
    return op.get_result()

  File ".../concat.py", line 423, in get_result
    copy=self.copy)

  File ".../internals.py", line 5425, in concatenate_block_managers
    return BlockManager(blocks, axes)

  File ".../internals.py", line 3282, in __init__
    self._verify_integrity()

  File ".../internals.py", line 3493, in _verify_integrity
    construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)

  File ".../internals.py", line 4843, in construction_error
    passed, implied))

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 19687), indices imply (2, 19685)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Erfan how can I solve this error...

Comment: Have you tried Googling the error message? I just did, and I got more hits than I could count. At a high level, you have 19687 columns in one DataFrame, and 19685 in the other, for a difference of two columns. Therefore, the DataFrames cannot be concatenated.

Comment: @Mike yes I did. And I’ve tried many. The problem seems to be that the data index of the different .txt files are different. But I couldn’t solve it. :/

Comment: You possibly have duplicate index values. Try: `df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)`

Comment: As @Mike already stated, the shape of your dfs differs. Is the concatenation over `axis=1`on purpose?

Comment: @Erfan yes. They shouldn’t be columns but rows. And only four columns except the date/time index.

Comment: Then remove the `axis=1` in your `pd.concat` line

Comment: @Erfan it has solved my problem. Please  add your solution as an answer! Thanks bro!

Comment: Done, glad I could help :) @MarlonHenriqueTeixeira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using `pd.concat` over the wrong axis. Remove `axis=1` out of your `pd.concat..` line, since `axis=0` is the default as can be found in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Just for your convencience. To get a cleaner dataframe, use `ignore_index=True` as well:

```
aux = pd.concat([aux, new_col], ignore_index=True,  sort=False)
```

Which gives a reset index back.

Comment: Glad I could help, added one more tip, you can test if you like it @MarlonHenriqueTeixeira

Answer (score 1):

Your DataFrames are of incompatible shape:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 19687), indices imply (2, 19685)
```

In other words, the problem is that 19687 != 19685. Whatever answer you come across is going to come out of the specifics of your data, which is probably not practical to share, given its size. You need to, at least, add or delete 2 rows somewhere. You'll need to investigate to determine what and where.

Comment: Considering the difference is 2, the likelihood is your header and and possibly tail.